# 3Ds Max 2015 Text fully merge effect

Tags: text, max, effect, 3ds

My question is i am working on 3ds max. i want text on my object. i know the option to write text... **Go to create>shapes>text**. But i dont want this type of method. i want text with object if i give any effect to object that also reflected into text.I attach example image also In this image text is perfectly merge with image i want the same text with fully merge with image.

[image: Perfectly merge and emboss]

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit it to polygon or mesh object first [this part, you will make it become object]

then you might need to subtract with the object you want to put it lookalike emboss

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response , Actually i am a beginner. Just two days before i am using this software so its difficult to find your option. Can you plz explain it more where this option located and how its done.

Comment: you can search in google or youtube about '3dsmax text to object' or follow this example video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlMiZOyJ6tc

Comment: Hi , i watch this video all steps are done but in last step when i click to (Pick Operand B) option and then click text my text goes invisible.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/z0i261a0h6rvn48/example.jpg?dl=0